# using Undistort() using a relatively undistorted lens causes barrel distortion

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I have a 9x6 checkerboard and the camera of an android phone I'm trying to calibrate, but the results are clearly inaccurate. I'm using the code here (https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/dc/dbb/tutorial_py_calibration.html)

with 14 images taken at a nice variety of viewpoints, and it results in the following before and after:

[image]

With intrinsics (in pixels):

```py
array([[1431.53077,    0.     ,  990.76893],
       [   0.     , 1431.28726,  769.96117],
       [   0.     ,    0.     ,    1.     ]])
```

and distortion coefficients of `[ 0.11317, -0.39682, -0.00024, -0.00032,  0.54855]`

which seems way too large for the camera. Anyone know what the issue could be?

Comment: Undistortion optimizes the distortion in the inner chessboard area (the outer squares aren't used). Since your undistorted area doesn't cover the whole image, it's very likely that the uncovered regions will get some stronger distortion. You could either use much more images, or try to measure the reprojection error of the chessboard region and if it is very low already, dont perform undistortion or fix mist of the parameters.

Comment: calibration isn't trivial. -- tilt the board, never hold it parallel to the image plane. -- chessboards are old tech, all corners need to be fully in view. that makes it hard to get samples in the corners of the camera's view, where it's most important to have some. I haven't personally tried it, but charuco boards don't have that requirement, you can just rake one over the view and it'll work. -- keep the board still. motion blur sucks. and so does rolling shutter.